# How reset tab history in Tabs on tab click using ReactNavigation 5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using React Navigation5. 
I have a tab navigator and want to clear history of tab on click tab. 
For example, I am on tab 1, and go to tab 2. 
From tab2, i navigate

screen1->screen2->screen3

Now If i click on tab, it should come to initial screen (screen1).
but its not working, it working in wrong way.
here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { CommonActions, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';


// Custom imports:
import StartScreen from '../screens/start/StartScreen';
import ProductsScreen from '../screens/products/ProductsScreen';
import AddCustomerScreen from '../screens/customers/AddCustomerScreen';
import CustomersScreen from '../screens/customers/CustomersScreen';
import WebviewScreen from '../screens/webview/WebviewScreen';

// Menu Screen
import MenuScreen from '../screens/menu/MenuScreen';
import CurrentAccountScreen from '../screens/menu/CurrentAccountScreen';
import AccountDetailScreen from '../screens/menu/AccountDetailScreen';
import AppInfoScreen from '../screens/menu/AppInfoScreen';
import MessagesScreen from '../screens/menu/MessagesScreen';

import { Colors, GlobalStyles } from '../constants';

import { Badge, CustomIcon } from '../components/icons';
import {
  iconStart,
  iconProducts,
  iconCustomers,
  iconMenu
} from '../components/icons/TabBarIcons';
import {
  IconLowbarAddOrder,
} from '../components/IconFiles';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

// Initial Parameters for WebView
let initParamsForWebView = {
  url: '',
  screenName: '',
  haveUser: false,
  user: false
};

/**
* Start Stack Navigator
**/
const INIT_START_ROUTE = 'Start';
function StartStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName={INIT_START_ROUTE}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={StartScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Webview"
        component={WebviewScreen}
        initialParams={initParamsForWebView}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


/**
* Products Stack Navigator
**/
const INIT_PRODUCTS_ROUTE = 'Products';
function ProductsStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName={INIT_PRODUCTS_ROUTE}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Products" component={ProductsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Webview"
        component={WebviewScreen}
        initialParams={initParamsForWebView}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

/**
* Menu Stack Navigator
**/
const INIT_MENU_ROUTE = 'Menu';
function MenuStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName={INIT_CUSTOMERS_ROUTE}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={MenuScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="CurrentAccount" component={CurrentAccountScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AccountDetail" component={AccountDetailScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AppInfo" component={AppInfoScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Webview"
        component={WebviewScreen}
        initialParams={initParamsForWebView}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


function resetStack(navigation, _route, _stack, _screen){
  console.log(_route);
  console.log(navigation);
  console.log('ResetStack Called');
  navigation.dispatch(
            CommonActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [
                    { name: _stack}
                ]
            })
        );
}

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME = 'StartStack';
export default function ParticipantNavigator({ navigation, route }) {
  // screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} 
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} 
      initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME}
      lazy='false'
      tabBarOptions={{}}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="StartStack"
        component={StartStack}
        options={{
          title: 'Start'
        }}

        listeners={{
          tabPress: e => {
            resetStack(navigation, route, 'StartStack', INIT_START_ROUTE);
          }
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="ProductsStack"
        component={ProductsStack}
        options={{
          title: 'Products'
        }}
        listeners={{
          tabPress: e => {
            resetStack(navigation, route, 'ProductsStack', INIT_PRODUCTS_ROUTE);
          }
        }}
      />

      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="MenuStack"
        component={MenuStack}
        options={{
          title: 'Menu'
        }}
        listeners={{
          tabPress: e => {
            resetStack(navigation, route, 'MenuStack', INIT_MENU_ROUTE);
          }
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Two issues in this code i am facing.

1. When I click on Tab, it goes to first tab instead of moving to first screen of Clicked tab.
2. When i come back to old tab, History not reset on that tab too.

any one can help me in this, Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

if you are wroking on tabs and then want to reset the tab then try this React Navigation 5 here is the link[see the documentation React Navigation 5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#unmountonblur)

```
<BottomTab.Screen
name="Post"
component={PostStack}
options={{
  unmountOnBlur: true,// set this props in your tab screen options
  title: 'Post',
  tabBarIcon: focused => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="Post" />,
}}
```

/>

Answer (score 2):

you can try this porp:unmountOnBlur

when you from ProductsStack to MenuStack,the ProductsStack will Unmount,

link is [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#unmountonblur)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with React Navigation 5.x

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66982007/10672805

The code below is for resetting multiple tabs.

```
TabNavigator
    Tab1: 'tab1_name' 
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenA
         - ScreenB

    Tab2: 'tabs_name'
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenC
         - ScreenD

    Tab3: 'tab3_name'
      StackNavigator
         - ScreenE
         - ScreenF
```

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab1_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenA' },
            { name: 'ScreenB' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab2_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenC' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab3_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenE' },
            { name: 'ScreenF' },
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  })
)
```

And with this code, the first page you see is `tab1_name` tab's `ScreenB` screen.

So, if you want to see `tab3_name` tab's `ScreenF` screen first after running the dispatch function, the code should be something like:

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab3_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenE' },
            { name: 'ScreenF' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab1_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenA' },
            { name: 'ScreenB' },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'tab2_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            { name: 'ScreenC' },
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  })
)
```

By the way, when you write down the `routes` of tab's `state`, it should follow the sequence of page stack. So that it would work as you expected.

```js
navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    routes: [
      {
        name: 'tab3_name',
        state: {
          routes: [
            // { name: 'ScreenE' },   // removed
            { name: 'ScreenF' },
          ]
        }
      },
      ...
```

If you omit the first stack page as above, `ScreenE` is not accessible but only `ScreenF` after running the dispatch function.

Hope this works for you.